# Python regex possible matches after a match

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern like this

```
name: steven
add: hyderabad
add: India

name: samuel
add: chennai
add: tamilnadu
add: India


...
```

the address lines(add:) can vary. How can i write a regex to capture names as well as the address contents?

Please note that each record is seperated by `\n\n` and each line of a record is seperated by a new line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: re.findall(r'name: (.*)\n(add:(.*)\n)', data). I am able to extract the name but can access a single add line

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to avoid regex altogether and just use a generator.  We can accumulate line after each name and then yield them in pairs

```
def gen(file):
    name = None
    addresses = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('name'):
            name = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        elif line.startswith('add'):
            addresses.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())
        else:
            if name is not None:
                yield (name, addresses)
                name, addresses = None, []
    if name is not None:
         yield (name, addresses)

with open(filename) as f:
    print(list(gen(f)))

 # [('steven', ['hyderabad', 'India']), ('samuel', ['chennai', 'tamilnadu', 'India'])]
```

Comment: While I appreciate writing in a function, i thought of checking if its possible through a regex to be simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can using `re` for parsing the input data:

```
data = """
name: steven
add: hyderabad
add: India

name: samuel
add: chennai
add: tamilnadu
add: India
"""

import re

for group in re.findall(r'(name:.*?)(?:(?=name:)|\Z)', data, flags=re.DOTALL):
    name = re.findall(r'(?:name:\s*([^\n]+))', group, flags=re.DOTALL)
    addresses = re.findall(r'(?:add:\s*([^\n]+))+', group, flags=re.DOTALL)
    print(name[0], addresses)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
steven ['hyderabad', 'India']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
samuel ['chennai', 'tamilnadu', 'India']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `name: [a-zA-Z]+\n(add: [a-zA-Z0-9]+\n)+`.

It catches groups of such structure:

```
name: ...
add: ...
...
add: ...
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/XtD3wm/1)